# sql server query problem

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT 
   'Registered End Users' AS 'Report Name',
   'Above Date Range' AS 'Desc',
   CONVERT(VARCHAR, COUNT(*)) AS VALUE
FROM 
    WAPI_CUSTOMERS C
WHERE 
    C.ID NOT IN (SELECT S.CUSTOMER_ID FROM WAPI_SUBSCRIPTIONS S) 
    AND 
       CASE C.BASIC_REG_DATE IS NULL THEN C.FULL_REG_DATE BETWEEN @FROM_DATE AND @TO_DATE
          WHEN C.FULL_REG_DATE IS NULL THEN C.BASIC_REG_DATE BETWEEN @FROM_DATE AND @TO_DATE 
       END
```

Actually I have two table named `wapi_customers` and `wapi_subscribers`. I have have get all rows of customer table which are not in subscriber table between user selected date range.

In customer table I have two types of customers like basic and full.

1. basic customers have `isbasic=1` and `basicregdate=somedate` and `isfull=0` and `fullregdate=null`
2. full customers have `isbasic=0` and `basicregdate=null` and `isfull=1` and `fullregdate=somedate`
3. case which are upgraded from basic to full:
   `isbasic=1` and `basregdate=somedate` and `fullregdate=1` and `fulldate=somedate`

Now I have to count customers which follow the above conditions means in case of basic 
we will use `C.BASIC_REG_DATE BETWEEN @FROM_DATE AND @TO_DATE` and in case of full 
`C.FULL_REG_DATE BETWEEN @FROM_DATE AND @TO_DATE` and in case of upgrade `C.FULL_REG_DATE or C.BASIC_REG_DATE BETWEEN @FROM_DATE AND @TO_DATE`

Plz help

Comment: has the course taught you left joins yet? They're much faster.

Comment: Question is make a query for this logic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, following is something would work for you:

```
where
 ( 
            (isbasic = 1 and basicregdate is not null and isfull=0  ) 
            and C.BASIC_REG_DATE BETWEEN @FROM_DATE AND @TO_DATE 
      )
or 
 ( 
            ( isbasic=0 and fullregdate=null and isfull=1 and fullregdate is not null) 
            and C.FULL_REG_DATE BETWEEN @FROM_DATE AND @TO_DATE 
      )
or
(
       (isbasic=1 and basregdate is not null and fullregdate=1)
       and C.BASIC_REG_DATE BETWEEN @FROM_DATE AND @TO_DATE
)
```

Comment: (isbasic=1 and basregdate is not null and fullregdate=1)
and C.BASIC_REG_DATE BETWEEN @FROM_DATE AND @TO_DATE  In this case i have to check both basic or full date